# Titanium Facebook Dialog does not appear

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

Im developing an "share on facebook" button.

But there is a problem, the facebook dialog is not prompted to the user.

I have tried the sample that titanium provide:

```
function facebook(){

    var fb = require('facebook');

    var data = {
        link : "http://www.appcelerator.com",
        name : "Appcelerator Titanium Mobile",
        message : "Checkout this cool open source project for creating apps",
        caption : "Appcelerator Titanium Mobile",
        picture : "http://developer.appcelerator.com/assets/img/DEV_titmobile_image.png",
        description : "You've got the ideas, now you've got the power."
    };

    fb.dialog("feed", data, function(e) {

            var toast = Ti.UI.createNotification({
            message:"Default",
            duration: Ti.UI.NOTIFICATION_DURATION_LONG
        });

            if(e.success && e.result) 
                toast.message = "Success! New Post ID: " + e.result;
            else {
                if(e.error) 
                        toast.message = e.error;
                else 
                    toast.message = "User canceled dialog.";
            }
        toast.show();
    });
}
```

The function is called correctly, but nothing appear.

Someone knows why? Maybe permissions? But i have read that for the dialog aren't required permissions!

thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself! 
Even if the Facebook Dialog not Require the Auth(), it require the init with an AppID.

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.appid = your_app_id_number;
```

With this worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.appid = FACEBOOK_APP_ID;
fb.permissions = ['publish_stream']; // Permissions your app needs
fb.forceDialogAuth = true;
fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert('Logged In');
    } else if (e.error) {
        alert(e.error);
    } else if (e.cancelled) {
        alert("Canceled");
    }
});
fb.authorize();
```